# sinon a spy function that exists on a controller (this)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have tricky function that I want to spy on.

```
 $rootScope.AlertsGlobal = {};

    this.updateHeight = function (clientHeight) {
    $rootScope.AlertsGlobal.clientHeight = clientHeight;

};
```

This refers to the angular controller

```
 var GlobalAlertsController = function() {
 }
```

like so ...

```
 var GlobalAlertsController = function() {
      this.updateHeight = function (clientHeight) {
    $rootScope.AlertsGlobal.clientHeight = clientHeight;
 }
```

The function lives inside  directives controller and is required by another controller (requires difference in unit test? ).

```
require: 'MainGlobalAlerts',
```

Inside of my unit test I mocked out my directive

```
html = angular.element("<my-directive> </my-directive")
element = $compile(html)($rootScope)
$rootScope.$digest(element)
scope = element.scope()    // note html and scope are defined below describe
```

I have tried to sinon spy this  **updateHeight()**  a couple of different ways.

```
sinon.spy(scope, 'updateHeight')

sinon.spy($rootScope, 'updateHeight')
```

However my error statement

```
 Typeerror: Attempted to wrap undefined property updateHeight as a function
```

Since  **updateHeight**   Is defined with this I am not sure how to call this method if I cannot spy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller instance (`this`) is not available on the scope, it has to be retrieved through [`controller` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods), with something like this:

```
element = $compile('<my-directive>')($scope)
var controllerInstance = element.controller('myDirective');
sinon.spy(controllerInstance, 'updateHeight');
```

To be able to reach controller instances through `$scope`, use controllerAs syntax in directive. It offers better testability, besides the regular controllerAs benefits.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try this out.  I do not have control over the way the code was written just tested